# Social Media Buttons Not Center in <div>

Tags: css, alignment, center

I try to center the social media buttons in a `<div>`, but it keeps on aligning left.

```
echo '<div class="socialWrapper">';
echo '<div class="fb-like" data-href=" '  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" style="vertical-align:top;zoom:1;*display:inline;"></div> ';
echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false"></a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script> ';
echo '<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div>';
echo '</div>';
```

CSS file

```
div.socialWrapper{
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Should it not be margin: 0 auto;? And maybe you could add a container div which has display: flex and align-items: middle;

Comment: That aligns centrally for me, doesn't need the margin either. That margin wouldn't even do anything without a defined width.

Comment: @EthanBristow doesn't have to be `0 auto`. `0` in `0 auto` applies to the top bottom margin. When you provide a single value to `margin` then that value is applied to top, bottom, right and left margins. The key to centering with auto margins is that the left and right margins need to be set to `auto` along with a width being defined, **[`margin: auto;` satisfies that](https://jsfiddle.net/ob3b81t2/)**.

Comment: The code is OK (albeit with a superfluous margin declaration) you have something else in your code pushing it left. Post a link?

Comment: hahaha width:100% with margin auto won't do anything - it's 100% width so how can you center it? If you want all it's contents to be centered make them inline-block elements and then your text-align will work on them

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `*display:inline`?

Answer (score 0):

try `div.socialWrapper{display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-direction: row;}`

Answer (score 0):

The parent `<div>`, `socialWrapper`, has a width of 100%, and will only appear centered by using `margin: 0 auto` if you give it a width of less than 100%.

`<div>` is a block-level element (its default behaviour is to be display as a block, so new elements will appear on a new line). Use `<span>` instead, because it is an inline element.

This means the nested `<div>` elements will need to be explicitly set as `display: inline-block`. (`text-align: center` will only be applied to elements whose default behaviour is `display: inline`, I think).

**HTML/PHP**

```
echo '<div class="socialWrapper">';
echo '<span class="fb-like" data-href=" '  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" style="vertical-align:top;zoom:1;*display:inline;"></span> ';
echo '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false"></a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script> ';
echo '<span class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></span>';
echo '</div>';
```

**CSS**

```
div.socialWrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I made a CodePen demo for you:

See the Pen [Social toolbar](http://codepen.io/vogelbeere/pen/gmZKbQ/) by Yvonne Aburrow ([@vogelbeere](http://codepen.io/vogelbeere)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

Comment: I am not sure about this. When I removed the google plus button, it align center, but when I added back the google plus, it align to the left. I think the google plus button has extra space at the back.

Comment: in that case, check the CSS being applied to Google Plus button. My CodePen works so I can only assume there's some extra CSS being applied to that button (and make sure it is in a `<span>` and not a `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

I manage to center social icons through following code in css:

```
.wrapper{
margin: auto;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: row;
max-width: 200px;
```

try this it worked for me.
(I set max-width to 200px because it suits to me best, you can use 
different number or dont need to use att all but in that case icons are spreaded al the way through div width.)